# Adam is an adaptive learning rate method, why people decrease its learning rate manually?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, computer-vision

Adam optimizer is an adoptive learning rate optimizer that is very popular for deep learning, especially in computer vision.

I have seen some papers that after specific epochs, for example, 50 epochs, they decrease its learning rate by dividing it by 10.

I do not fully understand the reason behind it.

How do we do that in Pytorch?

Answer (score 1):

There is no one-size-fits-all optimizer. Adam sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. If you look at what is used in different research papers, you would see different optimizers used. [There are some authors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/561049/why-does-adam-optimizer-seems-to-prevail-over-nadam-optimizer/561052#561052) who argue that you should use vanilla SGD. Adam's learning rate [may need tuning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/336065/35989) and is not necessarily the best algorithm. But there is also research showing that it may be beneficial to use other (that Adam's) [learning rate schedules](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/nn-learning-rate/). So it is not that easy, Adam isn't necessarily enough.